# Azure DevOps Server is not displaying process templates for projects

Tags: azure-devops-server-2020

I have an Azure DevOps Server 2020 Update 1 running on premise. When I look into the projects it does not show the process templates for existing projects anymore:

[image: Project List in Collection]

Also if I drill into a single project the template is not shown:

[image: No process template in project]

When I look into the templates on organization level all the templates are there but I cannot click on any of it und thus cannot determine which project uses which template:

[image: Process template list in Collection]

I already tried to create a new project. There I can select any of the process templates and the project gets created correctly. Afterwards the project is showing the same odd behavior.

I am running as Collection Administrator.

I'm about to shift to Azure DevOps Services and thus tried out the migration tool. Even the tool is not able to "see" the process information.

Comment: It seems to me as more users are experiencing this problem.
Very likely it's also related to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72213611/azure-devops-server-change-project-process-from-basic-to-agile). Can you please post this as a question on [microsoft developer community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com)?

Comment: No. We started all over again on a new DevOps Service Org.