# Azure DevOps Server: Change Project Process from Basic to Agile

Tags: azure, azure-devops-server-2020

I want to change an Azure DevOps 2020 project's Process from Basic to Agile and I'm following this [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/change-process-basic-to-agile?view=azure-devops-2020).

However, I can't select the projects in the part "Change the process". The word "Basic" is no link which should lead to the project's list with the basic process. Also the "..." menu next to it doesn't provide any expected link.
So the Url "https://myDevOps.com/DefaultCollection/_settings/process" is basically a dead end.
[image]

I am the Administrator of the DevOps and also the Collection Administrator and the project's Administrator so the permissions shouldn't be the problem.

Interesting enough, in the project list I can't see a value in the "Process" column, even if I create a complete new project from scratch with e.g. Agile process selected:
[image: project list]

Any ideas what might be the issue?

Comment: Same problem here, tripple checked the permissions, too. Shouldn't be the problem.

Comment: I noted that this is only an issue with our DefaultCollection.
The other collections I am able to see the value of the Process field and also am able to change project processes.

Comment: It seems to me as more users are experiencing this problem.
Very likely it's also related to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71840521/azure-devops-server-is-not-displaying-process-templates-for-projects). Can you please post this as a question on [microsoft developer community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com)?

Comment: No, I haven't found a solution. My best guess to this point is, that its a problem because our DefaultCollection has been migrated from a TFS Collection and MS couldn't transition everything clean from TeamFoundation Server to Azur DevOps. It fits to the fact, that with every new Collection the change isn't a problem.